# Hello there, I need a normal string from the random array

Tags: javascript

Well, the main problem is that i need a normal string from the random array's elements, if someone know how to do this, please (algorithm can be on python)

```js
function makeid(length) {
   let result           = '';
   let characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   let charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}

function randomNumber(min, max) {  
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min; 
}

let array = [];

for(i=0; i<=randomNumber(1, 10); i++){
    array.push(makeid(randomNumber(5, 7)));
}

for(i of array){
    console.log(i);
}


// i need something like 'a b c d'(values from the array)
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code that you have posted? What do you mean by "normal string"?

Answer (score 0):

I made edited your code.I hope it is what you wanted:

```html
function makeId(length) {
   let result           = '';
   let characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   let charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(getRandomInt(charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}

// Random number from 0 to max-1
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
const randomStrings = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    randomStrings.push(makeId(getRandomInt(15)));
}

console.log(randomStrings);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, but i need to make a sting from this random array, i don't even need that two functions, they are existing just for arrays creation.